# 'After' as an auxiliary verb

Tags: word-usage

This is from 'Mothers and Sons' by Colm Toibin.

> I met a whole load of fellows, they **were after being** in the pub.

I've never seen this kind before. I googled and looked up different dictionaries and found [one in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/after)  that seems to explain this.

I am trying to make a normal(?) sentence out of this.

> I met a whole load of fellows, they **had just been** in the pub.

Is this right?

Comment: Please cite the dictionary by name.

Comment: **had just been** is an idiomatic way to render that meaning.

Comment: Yes, it's very much a peculiarly Irish construction. Your paraphrase is correct, though I've found that this construction can even be used in place of **simple past tense**, ie. 'they were in the pub'. Not being a native colloquial Irish speaker though, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native English speaker from the US, I've never seen anything like, "I met a whole load of fellows, they were after being in the pub." As others have said, it looks like that's an expression in Irish English.

I would say

> "I met a whole load of fellows **who** had just been in the pub."

Your version is okay in terms of meaning, but you're comma splicing. (See https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/2/1/34/)

Comment: It's not a written statement. It's a conversation. He is telling his mother that he met them. Sorry I  didn't mention this. Thank you for posting an answer. Now, I can wrap this up.